# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0" when requiring a module using strict mode

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, module, strict

In `index.js` I have

```
'use strict';

const config = require('./config');
```

In `config.js` I have

```
'use strict';

const config = new function() {
  this.port = 3000;
  this.redirectUri = "http://localhost:" + this.port + "/auth";
}

module.exports = config;
```

On x64 Windows running node v6.9.5 this runs fine.

On a Raspberry Pi Zero (Raspbian Pixel, ARM v6) running node 6.10.2 however, I get the following error:

```
module.js:590
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /home/pi/pihas-api/config.json: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:587:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/pihas-api/index.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

I know this is because I'm using `'use strict';` in `config.js`, but I'm wondering why it *does* work on Windows, and whether or not there's a way to get this to work on the Pi Zero as well.

Comment: Why are you doing `new function() { ... }`?

Comment: I didn't want to export all of my configuration `const`s separately, so I tried putting them all into the same Object. This didn't allow me to initialize the Object in one go, however, as I couldn't access the `port` const *inside* the config Object during initialization, so I figured I'd use a function instead, which *does* allow me to use the `port` const during initialization, and still allows me to just call `config.port` from `index.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not Javascript. You cannot `"use strict";` in JSON.

Comment: My bad, it's actually `config.js`. I've edited the question.

Comment: The error messages don't agree. The SyntaxError stack trace clearly shows that the file is called `config.json`.

Comment: Ah, my bad, thanks! I can't believe I didn't catch that right away. 
My actual `config.js` contained some sensitive data, so I didn't add it to my git.